# Google redirect_uri with a path not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I'm using a redirect_uri to choose the page that's opened after Google Authentication. It works fine in dev, but not in production (both are using the same OAuth Client ID). I've added both the localhost and the production links in the Authorized redirect URIs section of the Client ID.

The production error looks like this (I'm replacing my actual domain with test.com). I'm confused because the link in the error matches the link I've added to the Authorized redirect URIs:

```
 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. The redirect URI in the request,
 https://www.test.com/target does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

So this works:

```
const gapiClientConfig: GapiClientConfig = {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: [ DISCOVERYDOCS ],
  scope: [ SCOPES ].join(' '),
  ux_mode: 'redirect',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/targetPage
};
```

But this does not:

```
const gapiClientConfig: GapiClientConfig = {
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  discoveryDocs: [ DISCOVERYDOCS ],
  scope: [ SCOPES ].join(' '),
  ux_mode: 'redirect',
  redirect_uri: 'https://www.test.com/targetPage
};
```

If I remove the path from the link, it works.

```
redirect_uri: 'https://www.test.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the changes to the OAuth client settings in the Google Cloud Console may not take effect immediately. Everything is working now.